# How to solve fix this problem in javascript

Tags: javascript

The user can choose the word on the left, that choice is added to the widow on the right. More accurately, that word should be added to a global array, then that array is displayed on the right. We want to do it that way, because it allows us to modify the word before it’s displayed.

The modification is that the letters chosen should be replaced by and * character, when the word is displayed on the window on the right. When the letter changes. The display on the window on the right should reflect that change. You do not want to maminpulate the words in the right window directly, because information is loss when a letter is replaced by a *, and the original letter cannot be recovered.

Note that for a select tag, you get the input value like you would any other input.

[image]

```js
var addword = document.getElementById('addword').value;
var letter = document.getElementById('letter').value;

var display = document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = addword;
```

```html
<select id="addword">
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
  <option value="tiger">tiger</option>
</select>

<select id="letter">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Where is your code that you need help fixing?

Answer (score 0):

A global array stores all the added words.

An event listener is registered on the letter `select` element to refresh the `#display` div whenever the selected letter changes (as long as there is at least one added word).

The `refreshDisplay` function maps the array of added words to an array of the same words but where every occurrence of the selected letter is replaced by an asterisk (`*`), using `[String.prototype.replace][1]`.

I added the placeholder text present in the provided image, and the letter select label text.

*Note that this implementation prevents adding the same word more than once (duplicates additions are ignored).*

```js
function refreshDisplay() {
  var letter = document.getElementById('letter').value;
  
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = addedWords.map(word => word.replace(letter, "*"));
}

const addedWords = [];

document.getElementById('addword').addEventListener("click", function() {
  const wordToAdd = document.getElementById('word').value;
  if (addedWords.indexOf(wordToAdd) == -1) {
    addedWords.push(wordToAdd);
    refreshDisplay();
  } // otherwise it is already there, so don't add a duplicate
});

document.getElementById('letter').addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (addedWords.length > 0) {
    refreshDisplay();
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="word">
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
  <option value="tiger">tiger</option>
</select>

<button id="addword">Add word</button>
Filter Letter
<select id="letter">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="display">Words you have added</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is, but if I understood correctly:

You could either use the replaceAll function:
addWord.replaceAll(letter, "*")
or
addWord.split(letter).join("*")

These methods return a new string and do not manipulate the original string directly.

Have I answered your question or have I missed something?

Therefore addWord would remain intact, whereas display would be modified with the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my quick answer.  You can run it at jsbin => https://jsbin.com/fefebifeyo/edit?html,js,output

It'll add each word for the first box.  I'll let you work through to get the second box working.

```
let addword = "";
let letter= document.getElementById('letter').value;

var display = document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = addword;

document.querySelector("#addword").addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (document.querySelector("#addword").value == ""){return;}
  addword += document.querySelector("#addword").value += " ";
  document.querySelector("#display").innerText = addword;
  }, false);
```

You can see it adds each word when you choose it.

[image: sample running]

Comment: It doesn't seem to replace the occurrences of the selected letter with `*` in the list of words...

Comment: I wasn't quite clear on OP's requirements for 2nd drop list so I didn't implement.  But wanted to provide a start to get the code running at least.